# Packages in Neos (Composer)

Tags: neoscms, flow-framework

So, I managed to install an instance of typo3 NEOS on my server. Everything looks fine and as expected. Is is functional as well.

Now I read something about the [formbuilder](https://flow-form-framework.readthedocs.org/en/stable/). I found a documentation on [how to install it](http://karsten.dambekalns.de/blog/installing-packages-for-flow.html) as well. From what I can tell (no experience in symfony2 / composer), the package is included, since the related folder + files are located and the right spot.

But now I'm stuck. How - or where am I supposed to use this extension? In [this video](https://vimeo.com/38155028) he shows how to use it, but not how to open it. I googled it but I'm not able to find anything that helps.

Maybe this isn't even just NEOS-related and a common thing in symfony, when installing packages? Do I have to define routes?

Using **Ubuntu 15.04** and **NEOS 2.1**. Everything installed like in this 
[guide](https://www.neos.io/develop/download.html) explains it.

Comment: With my (limited) Neos experience, I’d say that with a standard install, you should already have the form framework in `Packages/Application/TYPO3.Form`. There should be no need to manually install it. The blog post you refer to for installing is 2,5 years old – which is too old to use it as a reliable source of information when it comes to Neos.

Comment: The typo3.Form is not the same as the Typo3.FormBuilder. These are two different Packages

Comment: Thanks for this info. I saw that the documentation inside `Packages/Application/TYPO3.Form` includes docs on the form builder, so I assumed the code is included, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another package, depending on [typo3/formbuilder](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/formbuilder) - [simplyadmire/neos-form-builder-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/simplyadmire/neos-form-builder-bundle) it provides neos management module, routes, acl, nodetypes ect. - it works but have some small bugs.

So in your `composer.json` in require section add:

```
"typo3/formbuilder": "@dev",
"simplyadmire/neos-form-builder-bundle": "@dev"
```

Now run `composer update` - should install both packages. If you work on Production context, you need to flush cache `FLOW_CONTEXT=Production ./flow flow:cache:flush` on Development it's not required.

Next, to your main `Configuration/Routes.yaml` add those lines (it's from second package readme):

```
-
  name: 'SimplyAdmire.Neos.FormBuilderBundle'
  uriPattern: '<SimplyAdmireNeosFormBuilderBundleSubroutes>'
  subRoutes:
    SimplyAdmireNeosFormBuilderBundleSubroutes:
      package: SimplyAdmire.Neos.FormBuilderBundle
```

Login to neos backend. On main menu (top left hamburger) you should see new link "Form builder" `http://yourhost/neos/management/formbuilder`. If you have demo page installed, you will have already one form in list - Contact form. There is a link `New form` it looks like plain text and it leads to formbuilder you've seen on video. Remember to save your work (top left button). Now you can go back to page editor, and add new node of type form, in editor on right you should be able to select form you've created with formbuilder.